# Adding userform controls during runtime "Object variable or with block variable not set" error

Tags: vba, ms-project

My code below is giving an error on the line

`Set VM = AP.VBProject.VBComponents("ViewManager").Designer.Controls`

I have looked up many examples of working code and cannot figure out how mine is set up differently to cause an error.

The error is `Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set`

Thanks for any help.

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click()
    Dim View As String
    Dim FField As String
    Dim TField As String
    View = cmbView.Value
    FField = cmbFrmFld.Value
    TField = cmbToFld.Value

    'if it is the first add change one way, if after the first add change another
    If ViewManager.Height = 116 Then
        ViewManager.Height = ViewManager.Height + 64.5
    ElseIf frmViews.Height > 116 Then
        ViewManager.Height = ViewManager.Height + 30
    End If

    Dim AP As Project
    Set AP = ActiveProject
    Dim lbl As MSForms.Label
    Dim VM As Object

    Set VM = AP.VBProject.VBComponents("ViewManager").Designer.Controls
    With VM
        Set lbl = .Add("Forms.Label.1")
    End With

    With lbl
        .Left = 6
        .Top = ViewManager.Height - 32
        .Width = 156
        .Caption = View
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are using the VBIDE Forms Designer to add the control to you ViewManager form when it is loaded which is not possible.  You can see this adding the following code to your module and adding a watch on the 'VM' VBComponent where the mouse stops (right click and add watch).  You'll see that the 'Designer' property is 'Nothing' whereas if you run the same code when the form is not loaded you'll be able to access the Designer property and all it's properties.

```
Sub CheckVBComponent()
    Dim AP As Project, VM as VBIDE.VBComponent

    Set AP = ActiveProject
    'Note also this assumes that you've named your ViewManager correctly in the VBProject
    Set VM = AP.VBProject.VBComponents("ViewManager")

    'Add watch here
    Stop
End Sub
```

The simple workaround here is to add the control straight to the form at runtime and not use the VBIDE.  For example:

```
Sub AddLabeltoMSProject
   Dim frmLbl As MSForms.Label

   Set frmLbl = ViewManager.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")

   With frmLbl
       .Caption = "I really love labels"
       .Top = ViewManager.Height - 32
       .Left = 6
       .Width = 156
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

You are right about the Designer properties not being populated. I don't get a properties/methods list for the designer. 'ViewManager' is a custom userform though.

I tried your approach anyway and got a "Method or data member not found" error.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise it was on a userform.  My update should solve the problem for you.

Comment: Thanks CuberChase. I actually had code similar to what you have here previously, but (correct me if I'm wrong) I think your code will return the form to it's initial state each time the form is used.  I'd like the runtime changes to be permanent, which led me to using the designer.

Any ideas on how to make those changes permanent?

Comment: No, you're right, the change isn't permanent and the next time the form loads the label will be gone.  So yes, the only way to make a control on a form permanent through code is through the VBE Designer but if the form is loaded you might have to unload it remove it and rebuild it from scratch with the new control.  Not very feasible and actually not stable in VBA.  The only option might be through using my answer but to store what controls have been added (& their properties) within the Project and then check this when the ViewManager initialises and reload them there.  Does that make sense?

Comment: It does.  I think that is as good an answer as is posssible. Thanks again.

Comment: No probs.  Depending on how complicated the form is, storing the additional control in the project could be quite feasible and worth looking at.